# How do I install the python pymorph module?

Tags: software-installation, python

How can I install pymorph module for my code in Ubuntu? I tried the commands below but they didn't work.

```
sudo apt-get install pymorp
sudo apt-get install python pymorph
```

The message just said:

```
E: Unable to locate package pymorph
```

How can I install pymorph module?

Comment: This is because pymorph does not exist as package in the apt sources. Use `pip` as @Parto mentioned in his answer to install it.

Comment: @Teddy What versions of Ubuntu and Python are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @dufte has pointed out in his comment to the question, `pymorph` does not exist in the Ubuntu repositories. However, `pymorph` does exist in PyPI. The best way to install `pymorph` is to use `pip` inside a virtualenv; I would avoid using `sudo pip` because it is best to get `apt` manage your system packages and not let `pip` interfere with that. Assuming you are using Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 2, the code to install `pymorph` properly is:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install virtualenv
cd ~/<desired directory>  # cd to desired directory
virtualenv venv  # create virtualenv named venv for Python 2
source venv/bin/activate  # activate virtualenv
pip install -U pip  # upgrade pip
pip install pymorph
```

If you are using older versions of Ubuntu, replace `apt` with `apt-get`. If you want to use Python 3, replace `virtualenv venv` with `virtualenv venv -p python3`.

Comment: Why `virtualenv`? What's wrong with just `sudo pip install pymorph`?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055859/what-are-the-risks-of-running-sudo-pip, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028648/is-it-acceptable-safe-to-run-pip-install-under-sudo, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004708/osx-el-capitan-sudo-pip-install-oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted. The way I like to think about it is this: are you absolutely sure you need `sudo` to do what you need to do?

Comment: Well, yes, so that `root` and any other user can use this module becuase it is in `/usr/lib/python.../`

Comment: your code works for me @edwinksl. Thanks a  lot .

Comment: @Teddy Sounds good. By the way, do read https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#user-guide for a quick overview of how to use `virtualenv`; my post doesn't address all you need to know about it.

Comment: @edwinksl yes I have just read the link of user-guide and the activation as said. Now I have successfully pymorph, but when I use "import pymorph" in my python code, it still said that no pymorph module. Can you suggest me what is the possible issue?

Comment: @Teddy FWIW, I just tried again and I was able to import `pymorph` successfully. What error messages do you see? Also, can you tell us what the output of `which python` is? This can/should be a separate question if we can't resolve this quickly.

Comment: @edwinksl the message is " import pymorph
ImportError: No module named pymorph". I am using python 2.7. Thanks.

Comment: @Teddy What does `which python` say?

Comment: sorry, forget to put that. "/usr/bin/python", this is which python said. tks

Comment: @Teddy That means you forgot to activate your virtualenv. Remember to `source` the `activate` script as stated in the code in my post.

Comment: I think i did that. May be I make some error. Ok i will try it again. Tks @edwinksl

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41238/discussion-between-teddy-and-edwinksl).

Answer (score 3):

`sudo apt-get install pymorph` fails because pymorph does not exist as package in the apt sources.

If you want to know whether a package exists or not, you can run `apt-cache search [packagename]`. In this instance, running `apt-cache search pymorph` returns nothing.

```
parto@subroot:~$ apt-cache search pymorph
parto@subroot:~$
```

To install pymorph, use `pip`.

> pip - A tool for installing and managing Python packages
>
> pip  is  a  Python package installer, recommended for installing Python packages which are not available in the Debian archive.  It can work with version control repositories (currently only Git, Mercurial, and Bazaar repositories), logs output extensively,  and  prevents  partial installs by downloading all requirements before starting installation.

To install the python pymorph module:

1. Install pip (if not installed)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-pip
   ```
2. Use pip to install python pymorph

   ```
   sudo pip install pymorph
   ```

#### Edit

From [@Muru's](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru) comment, you can also try:

```
pip install --user pymorph
```

instead of

```
sudo pip install pymorph
```

Comment: Thanks @Parto, I was successfully install python-pip as you mentioned. But when i type the second command, I got message "user xxxx  is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/pip install pymorph' as root on xxxx". Does it mean i need permission from my IT or any error i make? thanks again.

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking, but should not you mention that the package is not available in the repos first?

Comment: @heemayl Sure. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: @Teddy Do you have root on the machine you are installing on? Are you the administrator?

Comment: I am not the administrator. But I am usually allowed to install the module on my PC.

Comment: It seems the sudoers file in that machine has not been configured correctly. Maybe you should get in touch with your admin for further help.

Comment: @Parto consider using `pip install --user` instead of `sudo pip`